# Which IBM JDK version to install Ubuntu?

Tags: java, websphere, ubuntu-20.04, ibm-jdk, ibm-jre

There are so many versions of IBM JRE/JDK available for linux machine at https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/java-sdk-downloads-version-80

Which version is available for ubuntu(to be specific ubuntu 20.04)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are multiple architectures.

You likely want the "Linux on AMD64/EMT64T" download. To be completely sure, check the output of `uname -m` for "x86_64".  If you're not sensitive to what architecture you're running, this is likely what you're using in the last decade.